# multiple square bracket values in JavaScript exports

Tags: javascript, commonjs

could someone explain, how js treats exports with multiple square brackets? Tried to google, but did not find anything usefull. e.g.:

```
exports["Bool"]["true"] = a => a["true"]();
exports["Bool"]["false"] = a => a["false"]();
```

Comment: `exports.Bool.true` - is a function here.

Comment: Are you referring to `CommonJS` modules in `Node.js`? If so, `module.exports["Bool"]["true"]` is actually incorrect and is equivalent to `module.exports.Bool.true` - since `Bool` is not an object and is actually `undefined`, you cannot set the `true` property on it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: This is result of Agda JS compiler, before these lines, line exports["Bool"] = {}; is produced, so if I understand correctly this line creates object ant those 2 line create methods for that object?